# How to animate CGAffineTransform smoothly as drag gesture is performed

Tags: iphone, ios, cgaffinetransform, uipangesturerecognizer

I understand the various ways of detecting drag gestures just fine (currently I'm using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`), but my understanding of transformations is limited, so I'm not sure if/how this is possible.  Essentially, what I want to have is a scaling transformation applied to a UIView at the same *pace* (for lack of a better word) as the user performs a drag gesture elsewhere on the screen.  In other words, as the user drags up, I want the size of my transforming UIView to increase proportionally to the position of that gesture, and if the user then starts dragging down, it should start to shrink proportionally.

Hopefully that makes sense.  As a dummy example, just imagine a slider that you can adjust to change the size of a UIView in real time.  Is there a good way to make those sorts of incremental and constant size updates with `CGAffineTransform`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your pan gesture handler, you simply grab `translationInView` or `locationInView`, calculate a scale from that, and then update the transform accordingly. For example:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    static CGAffineTransform originalTransform;

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        originalTransform = self.viewToScale.transform;
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view];
        CGFloat scale = 1.0 - translation.y / 160.0;
        self.viewToScale.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(originalTransform, scale, scale);
    }
}
```

You can play around with the `scale` calculation depending upon precisely what you want to do, but hopefully you get the idea.

Personally, I'd rather use the pinch gesture recognizer for resizing (it's a UI that users have been trained on, it gives you the `scale` factor right out of the box, etc.), but whatever works for you. If you did a pinch gesture recognizer, it might look like:

```
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    static CGAffineTransform originalTransform;

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        originalTransform = self.viewToScale.transform;
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        self.viewToScale.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(originalTransform, gesture.scale, gesture.scale);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect - the missing link for me was the idea of always applying transformations to what you called `originalTransform`, so I'm well on my way now.  I agree that in most cases, of course a pinch gesture makes most sense for scaling.  In this case, however, I'm playing with creative ways of transitioning between views, and this scale is really just a fancy side-effect during a drag-triggered transition.  Thanks a lot for the thorough answer!

Answer (score 0):

I found the best approach is to use locationInView so that you can equate a location offset in pixels with a scale. For example, if the circle is placed in the centre of the view:

```
func dragDot(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let locationX = recognizer.location(in: self.view).x

    // Expand and contract the circle
    let locationXOffset = locationX - self.view.center.x

    // We need scale to be 1 when locationXOffset = circle radius
    let scale: CGFloat = locationXOffset / (self.widthOfCircle / 2)

    self.ring.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
}
```

If the circle isn't in the centre of the view then replace `self.view.center.x` with the initial location of the circle.

This method will work across all devices and screen resolutions and will avoid the requirement to calibrate a constant

Comment: you should seriously mention :  what is widthOfCircle ? otherwise do not expect up votes..